# How to download synced application data from Samsung Cloud?

Tags: samsung, cloud

My Android Samsung S7 smartphone is broken, so I wanted to access my memo which I have backed up at Samsung Cloud. **I don't have another smartphone. I just need to download the data to the PC and dig the data out of the files.** But I don't know how to download those data. THere doesn't seem to be a link for download:

[image]

I went to Samsung Cloud, but here also is no link to download:

[image]

How do I download this as a file to PC?

Comment: [This video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IXoRxqXQePM) says you can download Samsung Gallery app (from Microsoft store) on windows 10 laptop and sync to PC

Comment: @beeshyams the [Samsung Gallery app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/samsung-gallery/9nblggh4n9r9?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) seems to just "show photos and videos". I was asking about how to download other application data like Memo. Basically, there should be some option like "download everything", e.g. in a zip file.

Comment: I don't have any Samsung device ; pointed to that video, just in case it helps. All the best

Comment: Based on the screenshots it looks like you are resident of the EU. In this case the GDPR states that you can contact an online/cloud provider and ask to retrieve all the data they have stored about you. This should include your stored data like your memos. May be it is worth a try.

Comment: @Robert wow, amazing advice, thanks!! Didn't know this!