# How and where do I access my S Notes on Samsung Galaxy Note 8?

Tags: notes, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I have ~1400 S-Notes that use ~40 GB of internal memory on my Samsung Galaxy Note 8. Where are the S-Note files located? How do I access them directly? Is there a way the enable access to the S-Note files? Are there any tools that give access to all files on the phone?

SmartSwitch doesn't have enough room to back them up anymore (needs 23 GB of internal memory only apparently).

- I've tried finding them using the Android Studio Device File Explorer on the Note 8, but can't find the files. On Samsung Galaxy Note 2, they were located at `/storage/emulated/0/S Note`. This directory on the Note 8 has only one small text file.
- I've also made backups using ADB (`adb backup -apk -obb -system -shared -all -f F:\samsung\note8\2021_09_06_backup.ab`), but the backup does not seem to contain the S-Note files. It also does not backup everything maybe due to lack of space.
- An ADB pull (`adb pull /data/data/com.samsung.android.app.notes F:\samsung\note8\` and `adb pull "/storage/emulated/0/S Note" F:\samsung\note8\`) of that directory only returned the small text file.

With only 500 MB of free internal space left, I've resorted to having to delete old notes now! The S-Note trash holds onto the deleted files for 15 days before actually deleting them but gives the file space back somehow.

I don't understand why I have to work so hard to access my S-Notes files. It's hard to use the S Note files on my Windows computers now after an S-Note upgrade that changed the file format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I access the Memo data without rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230757/can-i-access-the-memo-data-without-rooting)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I access the Memo data without rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230757/can-i-access-the-memo-data-without-rooting)