# Do I need a Samsung phone to recover notes from the 'Memo' app on the dead Samsung phone?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-s7, google-backup

My Samsung Galaxy S7 (with Android 8.0) is dead. I need to buy a new phone now and recover all my data from the automatic google backup. I wrote numerous notes to the default `Memo` app (which produces the undecodable `memo.nmmm` file; it is *not* [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.app.notes&hl=en&gl=US); i cannot find it in the app store, it was on the S7 by default). Do I have to buy Samsung phone to be able to recover that from a backup, or will any Android phone do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I access the Memo data without rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230757/can-i-access-the-memo-data-without-rooting)

Comment: @Robert unfortunatelly not :-)) That is actually my quesiton a while ago and there is no satisfactory answer till now (at least not without hacking). Here I am just asking for a simple 'buy the phone and use it' scenario.

Comment: I kind of doubt that Samsung's own memo is stored in Google Backup in the first place (note that apps can opt-out from Google Backup). Possibly on Samsung's own backup service: [Samsung Cloud](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/app/samsung-cloud), but still no guarantee since I don't have Samsung devices to test.

Comment: the apk itself can be obtained from ROM/firmware download with sdat2img or simg2img